# Pass promise parameter to nested directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Unfortunately the code is in Typescript but hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction. We want to embed the tags-input directive in a directive. It accepts a promise to filter the data. I want to embed the control in another directive and pass the promise from there. What I have done works but the parameter isn't passed. It's a bit difficult to explain so I'll show a cut down version of the code. Cheers, Chris.

Here is the parent directive

```
<sn-location-selector auto-complete="Model.Populate($query)" browselist="Model.Cache.CachedLocations" ng-model="Model.SelectedLocations2"></sn-location-selector>
```

The Model.Populate has a $query parameter which is not "passed back" to the page from the autocomplete.

```
        control.directive("snLocationSelector", ["Cache", "$rootScope", "$timeout",(Cache: Services.CacheService, Root: ng.IRootScopeService, $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService): any =>
        {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                templateUrl: "/control/snlocationselector.html",
                require: "ngModel",
                scope: {
                    disabled: "=?ngDisabled",
                    ngModel: "=",
                    autoComplete: '&',
                    browselist: "="
                },
                //replace: true,
                link:
                {
                    pre: (scope, element, attributes, controller: ng.INgModelController): void =>
                    {
                        scope.innerAutoComplete = scope.autoComplete;

                    },
                    post: (scope, element, attributes, controller: ng.INgModelController): void =>
                    {

                    }                                                
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Here is the control on the inner directive

```
<tags-input class="dashboard-tags" ng-model="ngModel"
            id="{{id}}"
            name="{{controller.$name}}"
            display-property="Name"
            add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
            on-tag-added="BrowseAddTag($tag)"
            on-tag-removed="BrowseRemoveTag($tag)"
            placeholder="Start typing a location or division...">
    <auto-complete source="inner-auto-complete($query)" min-length="1" load-on-focus="true" highlight-matched-text="false"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope function names must not be transformed to dashed form. Try using `innerAutoComplete` instead of `inner-auto-complete`

```
<tags-input class="dashboard-tags" ng-model="ngModel"
            id="{{id}}"
            name="{{controller.$name}}"
            display-property="Name"
            add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
            on-tag-added="BrowseAddTag($tag)"
            on-tag-removed="BrowseRemoveTag($tag)"
            placeholder="Start typing a location or division...">
    <auto-complete source="innerAutoComplete($query)" min-length="1" load-on-focus="true" highlight-matched-text="false"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. I suspect it's something to do with this

  pre: (scope, element, attributes, controller: ng.INgModelController): void =>
                        {
                            scope.innerAutoComplete = scope.autoComplete;
                            
                        },

I'm trying to assign the outer promise to the inner one but I suspect this isn't the proper way to do it

Comment: I don't see any code related to promises in your snippets. `scope.innerAutoComplete = scope.autoComplete;` does assign a *function* to another member.

Comment: Model.Populate($query) the function at the top return a promise which is bound in the markup. I'm really new to Angular so apologies if I'm a little unclear! Thanks